# Is there a natural language that doesn’t use an action verb to describe death?

Tags: linguistic-typology, verbs, sociolinguistics

English uses “activity” verbs such as the verb “to be” to describe that a person is dead, as in “He is dead,” or “He died.”  Is there a language that doesn’t do this?
I know that some languages have more capability of expression than others, and English is very capable, however I don’t believe it is capable of describing “death” without using a verb, and I cannot think of any English verb that doesn’t at least imply either motivation or activity of some kind, so I would like to know if any language other than English has this capability.

Comment: _Run_ is an action verb. _To be_ is not an action verb. It's an auxiliary that's required for progressive, passive, predicate adjectives, and predicates nouns.  Are you asking whether every language has a predicate adjective construction that can mean 'be dead'?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, German and derivatives qualify.  Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/​daudaz exists as *tot*, but the actual verb *dawjana* has no descendant like English *die* in modern High German.  It still requires the copula though, like any other adjective.  And it is more of a defect than a capability.

Comment: I'm not looking for a technical answer so much as an emotive one.  "To be" is an action verb in this sense, since "being" involves the "act" of being.  As such, even a rock is taking action when it "is" a rock.  What I'm looking for is something which is not in English, but might be in some other language, just as the proverbial "eight words meaning snow" in Inuit, if you get my drift.  I'm exploring an idea I have that involves how we language our existence, and thought this might be a way forward.

Comment: In Polish, it is usual to say *ktoś nie żyje*, literally "someone not lives" to say that someone died.

Comment: There's an expressive Czech idiom, *a je po [něm]*, literally "and it's after/past [him]". However, it's more of a "so much for him" and can equally — or even more often — refer to the destruction or expiry of inanimate or abstract things.

Comment: I have downvoted the question because it's based on an incorrect premise: *English uses “activity” verbs such as the verb “to be”*. *To be* is **not** an "action verb", but a part of the *to be dead* **predicate**. That's a misunderstanding of the role of *is* in "he is dead" and hence the question should be re-formulated to make sense.

Comment: haha 'snow', 'get my drift', I see what you did there. Also. "we language our existence. You're _really_ weirding language now. You say that 'to be' is an action verb (not what most people think of but that's another thing). In English what is an example for you of a _non_ - action verb?

Comment: Mitch, Thank for the comment.  And no, I cannot think of any verb that doesn't involve the activity of the verb itself - that's what caused this issue.  A comment below mentions the Bantu language Matumbi as an example of a language that doesn't require verbs, but I don't know if it can express something which English cannot: the state of deadness of a person without using some kind of activity.  It sounds promising however.

Answer (score 2):

The English copula “is” (and related forms) is a verb, and so is “die/died”. There are various criteria that allow you to argue pretty convincingly that “be” and “die” are verbs, also that “dead” is an adjective. A very basic test for the verb status of “be” is subject-verb agreement: the copula agrees with the subject. English sentences can’t describe *anything* without using a verb – this is a basic structural fact of English. Many languages have sentences without any verb, dispensing with the requirement for a verb “be” in sentences with stative predicates, analogous to English “John is dead/sick/tall”.

The Bantu language Matumbi is such a language. You can convey the present state “The person (muundu) is dead” either using a verb – *muundú a-wíile* (tense inflection tells you that this is a verb; *a-* is a subject-agreement prefix), or using an adjective *without* any verb – *muundú ŋ-waá*. The adjective *ŋ-waá* agrees with the noun *muundu*, and the prefix for agreement *ŋ-* is used only on nouns and adjectives, and not on verbs. Additionally, by using a different tense form of the verb, they can convey “the person died”, as *muundú a-a-wíile*. It may be just as common for languages to *not* require a verb to express stative predicates as it is to require a copula.

I leave untouched the reasonably large set of languages where there is no reason to distinguish adjectives and verbs at all.

As for the problem of translation, if we take an "accurate translation" to be one that conveys all and only the connotations and denotations of the original utterance into a structurally similar (short) text in a target language, then "accurate translations" are usually very hard to obtain. The meanings of tenses don't generally line up perfectly across languages, but "good enough" is possible. In the specific case of Matuumbi to English, there may be some subtle nuance about emphasis associated with the adjective construction versus the inflected verb construction, but in my (defeasible) opinion "The person is dead" is good enough as a translation for both utterances. Whatever subtle differences exist in the two constructions of Matuumbi, it is possible to encode that in a more long-winded translation into English.

Comment: Helpful comment.  Would it follow that it would not be possible to accurately translate some sentences from Matumbi to English? If English is limited by its verb requirement and Matumbi is not, Matumbi might be able to express some issues more accurately, such as the "John is dead." example. Would you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Some languages do not use a verb in a sentence of Subject + Adjective. If 'dead' exists as an adjective in those languages, then they could say, *He dead*, just like they can say *He big* or *He happy*. I think Russian might be an example. There is still a verb in Russian that means 'to die', though.

Comment: it will help if you expand your answer (got to help center to know more about it), add references of the languages that do not use a verb maybe explain in detail etc. if not, if you think that this is enough, put this in a comment, as this is not a full-bodied answer.

Comment: The reference to languages with optional or zero copulas hints at the incorrect premise in the question. English is a language that can express someone's being dead without an "activity verb" because *he is dead* does not have one, technically or (in my experience) emotively. It's hard to imagine which verbs qualify as "not activity verbs" if *to be* falls through the sieve!

Comment: Luke.... "It's hard to imagine which verbs qualify as "not activity verbs" if to be falls through the sieve!"  Precisely. I believe that our experience shapes our language, but because of that shaping, limits our language to our collective experience.  Thus, it is virtually impossible to describe what one might call the indescribable - that which is outside the experience of our ancestors, including death itself.

Answer (score 0):

Decades ago, another student of the Spanish language and I were taken by a newspaper clipping on a bulletin board in a building on the Ohio State campus where staff conducted many foreign language classes. The clipping announced, "Menéndez Pidal deja de existir." To me this phraseology hints at a negation of action.

Comment: Thank you, Bill.  I looked up your phrase using Google translator, and got back this:  "Menéndez Pidal ceases to exist."  And yes, of course Google is probably like throwing horseshoes ("pretty good" is okay for most purposes, but not for all), but... if it is correct, I would say that "ceases" is an active verb, since I would take the act of "ceasing" as an action just as "stopping" is an action. So I continue the search.

Comment: This seems to confuse euphemisms for dying with the question of how death is normally expressed. Death being taboo in some cultures might obscure the question; on the other hand, it could be a driver for there not being a straightforward way to express death. But Spanish has *morir* (and I know it even though I don't speak Spanish) so this is just tangential.